# Pandas - Slicing a bigger dataframe into smaller dataframes using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

Again, a python newbie -- but constantly learning.

I have a DataFrame below as follows:

Printing one line above and one line below tags=QQQ

```
       timestamp    close    high     low     open    tags   vol  new_column
719   2002-11-13  54.2400  55.9300  54.1100  55.3600  None  536    0.002    
720   2002-11-14  55.9900  57.0000  55.8700  56.9900   QQQ  391    0.032    
721   2002-11-15  56.6000  56.9200  55.6700  56.6900  None  387    0.010    
3204  2012-09-26  30.2800  30.6000  30.0400  30.1650  None  546   -0.021    
3205  2012-09-27  30.1700  30.4000  29.8900  30.1600   QQQ  471   -0.003    
3206  2012-09-28  30.1800  30.2600  29.7400  29.7600  None  542    0.0003     
3534  2014-01-22  36.2600  36.3200  35.7500  35.9300  None  219   -0.015    
3535  2014-01-23  36.0900  36.1300  35.5200  36.0550   QQQ  430   -0.004    
3536  2014-01-24  37.4500  37.5500  36.5300  36.8050  None  763    0.037
```

How can I create 'n' (in this case 3) dataframes, with unique names, consisting of data which is one above and one below the tags=QQQ ?
I am thinking of using a for loop but have not achieved any success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a Series of markers that will be used to identify the first rows of the dataframes:

```
marks = df['tags'].shift(-1)
```

Convert the None's to NaNs (for further filling) and QQQ's to 1's (for further counting):

```
marks[marks=='None'] = np.nan # I assume that 'None' is a string
marks[marks=='QQQ'] = 1
```

Calculate the cumulative sum and fill the gaps:

```
marks = marks.cumsum().fillna(method='ffill')
```

Finally, group by the markers but take only the first three rows from each fragment, in case there are gaps between the QQQ blocks:

```
df_list = [x.iloc[:3] for _,x in df.groupby(marks)]
```

Comment: This does assume that `±1` from `QQQ` leaves no gaps, but if that is the case then you can simply group by `3`, which is probably easier  `df_list = [x for _, x in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3)]`

Comment: @AChampion See the updated answer (it does not assume the contiguity anymore).

Comment: Looks good, hard to tell if the OP has any contiguity issues or if simply grouping by 3 would solve the OPs issue.

Comment: @AChampion Post your comment as a separate answer, just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses. To answer the queries above- I need to get 3 different dataframes created out of this, it can be up to N since the data I have exceeds 25000 rows. There is no contiguity issues, simply grouping by 3 would solve the problem. I just need to have 3 or n new dataframes on which I can perform other computations like mean before QQQ and mean after QQQ and so on. @DYZ